# DateTimePicker In MVC using JQUERY Showing Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I am using MVC4 and JQuery.In my form mulitiple datetime pickers .some time it will fire some times not.
Showing error in Browser Console Is,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inline' of undefined
(anonymous function)
jQuery.event.dispatch

elemData.handle.eventHandle

jQuery.event.trigger

(anonymous function)

jQuery.extend.each

jQuery.fn.jQuery.each

jQuery.fn.extend.trigger

jQuery.fn.(anonymous function)

$.extend._updateDatepicker jquery-ui.min.js:5

$.extend._showDatepicker

jQuery.event.dispatch

elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

HTML:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AGREEMENT_FROM, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', showAnim: 'slideDown' 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: can you paste the code where you have used the JQuery DatePicker?

Comment: In Razor:@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AGREEMENT_FROM, new { @class = "datepicker" })                                                                      Jquery :    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker(
      {
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        showAnim: 'slideDown'
      });
    });

Comment: Is this text box for the date picker part of a dynamically loaded div?

Comment: Did you include jQuery ui library to the page ?

Comment: yes.In this page 4 date time picker.One is firing ,but remaining is not firing always.sometimes firing.I included UI. Firing datetimepicker  contains default value. Remain datetimepicker is nullable model field